# dom-to-image generates only blank white image from html

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, rendering

I have a page that has a div element with **id='cart'** , and i want to be able to take screenshot of this html element. I used **html2canvas** and it worked fine (code is below) , but it was slow at "rendering " , so i tried **dom-to-image** library as it came to addresse this **slow rendreing** of html2canvas , i checked this library and it worked for many poeple , but for me i cant get it to work , it always **generates blank white image**.

**Here is the code snippet i used for dom-to-image:**

```
var cart = document.getElementById('cart')
    domtoimage.toPng(cart)
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = dataUrl;                               
        document.getElementById('test').appendChild(img);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
    });
```

****the code i used for html2canvas (working):****

```
    $('#cart').html2canvas({
         background :'#0A4361',
         color: '#cce3ff',
         onrendered: function (newCanvas) {
            $('#test img').attr('src',newCanvas.toDataURL());
         }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I did a test on [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-forest-0t9nj?file=/src/index.js:0-363) and it seems to work fine, a bit blurry though

Comment: This would be better as a comment since it doesn't really answer the question.